# european-calendar-style not working

Tags: org-mode, calendar, diary, format

I have the following in my `init.el` file:

```
(setq org-agenda-span 36)
(setq org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1)
(setq european-calendar-style t)
```

However, diary blocks are still interpreted as month first, then day, then year:

```
*** Urlaub!
   <%%(diary-block 02 11 2018 10 11 2018)>
```

is interpreted as "February, 11th, 2018 - October, 11th, 2018".

My Emacs version is: `GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21) of 2017-09-22, modified by Debian`

My Org-Mode version is: `Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /usr/share/emacs/25.2/lisp/org/)`

I remember, that I had it working correctly before. Maybe the issue arose when I updated to Emacs 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `european-calendar-style` disappeared at some point (I have it as a commented line in my doemacs file).  You should use `calendar-date-style`:

```
(setq calendar-date-style 'european)
```

This can be found from the docstring of `diary-block`:

> (diary-block M1 D1 Y1 M2 D2 Y2 &optional MARK)
>
> Block diary entry.
>
> Entry applies if date is between, or on one of, two dates.  The order
>   of the input parameters changes according to ‘calendar-date-style’
>   (e.g. to D1, M1, Y1, D2, M2, Y2 in the European style).

and then from the docstring of `calendar-date-style`.

Comment: Docstrings can be found using `M-x`, `describe-*`(replacing the asterisk with `function`, `variable` and others), `RET` and then entering the item you want to read the docstring of.